# fread not reading struct

Tags: c

I have the following code that writes structs to a file like so:

```
void write_assignments_to_file(list* assignments, FILE* file)
{
    while (assignments != NULL) {
       fwrite(assignments->a, sizeof(assignments->a), 1, file);
       assignments = assignments->next;
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

This is writing to the file but when I try to read the file again it hangs my code for reading looks like:

```
list* read_assignments_from_file(FILE* file)
{
    Assignment* assignment;

    list* item; 
    item = NULL;

    while ( fread(assignment, sizeof(assignment), 1, file) ) {
        printf("Reading an assignment in");
        insert(item, assignment);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return item;
}
```

My insert method looks like:

```
list* insert(list* assignment_pointer, Assignment* new_assignment)
{
    list* ap = assignment_pointer;
    if(assignment_pointer != NULL){
        while (assignment_pointer->next != NULL) {
           assignment_pointer = assignment_pointer -> next;
        }
        assignment_pointer -> next = (struct list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
        assignment_pointer = assignment_pointer -> next;
        assignment_pointer -> next = NULL;
        assignment_pointer -> a = new_assignment;
        return ap;
    } else {
        assignment_pointer = (list*) malloc (sizeof(list));
        assignment_pointer -> next = NULL;
        assignment_pointer -> a = new_assignment;
        return assignment_pointer;
    }
}
```

My struct definition for Assignment looks like:

```
typedef struct Assignment {
    char* moduleTitle;
    char* moduleId;
    char* title;
    char* author;
    time_t date_set;
    time_t date_due;
    int weighting;
} Assignment;
```

So whats causing my program to hang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a refresher on structs and pointers.

```
Assignment *assignment;
fread(assignment /*which is not set*/, sizeof(assignment) /*probably 4*/, 1, file);

/* Should look more like */
Assignment ass;
fread(&ass, sizeof(ass), 1, file);
```

There may be other issues, but this should get you started.

You should probably include the stuct definition for assignment, but I think you have the same problem in the write()

```
sizeof(assignments->a); /*size of a pointer not an object*/
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to guess the problem is reading into an uninitialized pointer.  You have no memory allocated for `assignment`. You probably want something more like this:

```
list* read_assignments_from_file(FILE* file)
{
    Assignment assignment;

    list* item; 
    item = NULL;

    while ( fread(&assignment, sizeof(assignment), 1, file) ) {
        printf("Reading an assignment in");
        insert(item, &assignment);
    }
```

Note also that your original code takes `sizeof(assignment)`, which will not do what you expect when it is declared as `Assignment* assignment;`.  It will give you the size of an `Assignment*`, which is the size of any other pointer - 4 bytes on a 32-bit system, or 8 on a 64-bit.